# The return type is incompatible with Activity.getActionBar()Error when greendroid project is imported on eclipse. How can I fix it?

Tags: android, eclipse, import, greendroid

I'm using the quickActionWidget from the greendroid library in my project. But when I import the greendroid project into eclipse it throws an error saying return type is incompatible with Activity.getActionBar(). I think the method is conflicting with the method default Actionbar of android. How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I get your question correctly but try to call getSupportActionBar instead of getActionBar

Comment: I changed the Android version under properties to 2.3.3 where ActionBar is not included in the API and the error was fixed.